# How to make OPENROWSET work with sp_MSforeachdb

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Suppose I have this query

```
      declare @sql varchar(max)
      SET @sql = 'USE [?];   
      insert into table
      SELECT  *
      FROM    OPENROWSET( ''SQLNCLI'',
                          ''Server=SERBERNAME;Trusted_Connection=yes;'',
                          ''SET FMTONLY OFF; SET NOCOUNT ON; exec db_name().dbo.sp_procedure''
                  ) '

                  EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @sql
```

As you know `sp_MSforeachdb` is used to run procedure among all db's.
In above problem, for many reasons, I **have to** use `OPENROWSET`.

But, in `OPENROWSET`, you have to specify db name, so that it runs correctly. How I can make above work on every single db (make use of somehow `db_name()`)?

Currently error is:

> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "(null)" returned message "Deferred prepare could not be completed.".

Comment: /You are trying to loop all the databases in a server then why you need openrowset?

Comment: @KannanKandasamy, just updated post. I want to insert into table stuff from SP. If I do insert..exec, that throws error that it can't do nested insert..exec. So, I'm trying to use OPENROWSET here

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this:

```
declare @sql varchar(max)
  SET @sql = 'USE [?];          
     SET NOCOUNT ON; 
     exec dbo.sp_procedure'
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @sql
```

Comment: just updated post. I want to insert into table stuff from SP. If I do insert..exec, that throws error that it can't do nested insert..exec. So, I'm trying to use OPENROWSET here